# How to Update a Column

Tags: sql-server, sql-update

I have SQL Express 2012 with a table that I added a column (integer) for a Word Count and the table already has a few hundred rows. I am not sure how I update the column to have the word count from the "entry" column.

I created a query that shows me the data, but how do I use this to update the table to store the Word Count for each entry?

```
SELECT 
  ID, 
  [UserName],
  [DateCreated], 
  LEN([Entry]) - LEN(REPLACE([Entry], ' ', '')) + 1 AS 'Word Count'
FROM [dbo].[Notes]
```

Comment: If you want this to be accurate you should use a computed column here instead of trying to keep the values up to date using an Update statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The verb in the SQL language to update data in a table is not surprisingly `UPDATE`. [The documentation has the full syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/ms177523.aspx).

If you want to update all rows and there are no `NULL` values in the `Entry` column (that would make the calculation fail) then this query will update a column named `WordCount`:

```
UPDATE Notes SET WordCount = LEN([Entry]) - LEN(REPLACE([Entry], ' ', '')) + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this piece of code.

```
UPDATE Notes SET
WordCount = LEN([Entry]) - LEN(REPLACE([Entry], ' ', '')) + 1
```

This should then update all rows in the table with the word count for that row.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you could do this so that your values are always current. Two big advantages here. First, you don't have to ever update your table. Second, the values will ALWAYS be current even if somebody updates your table with a query and doesn't update the WordCount.

```
create table #test
(
    Entry varchar(100) 
    , WordCount as LEN(Entry) - LEN(REPLACE(Entry, ' ', '')) 
)

insert #test
select 'two words' union all
select 'three words now'

select * from #test

drop table #test
```